# Ubuntu 18.04 sftp user cant access /var/www

Tags: sftp, ubuntu-18.04

OK, I'm a Linux newbie...
I followed this tutorial https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-setup-sftp-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-with-vsftpd

My objective is to create a new user with access vía SFTP to /var/www

Following the tutorial, I edited sshd_config

`sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

and added this to the file:

```
Match group sftp
ChrootDirectory /home
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

and restarted SSH.

`sudo service ssh restart`

I created a new group

`sudo addgroup sftp`

and a new user.

`sudo useradd -m sftpuser -g sftp`

I set the user password.

`sudo passwd sftpuser`

After this, when I try to connect to the server using SFTP, it works but when I go to /var/www, I get this error in FileZilla:

```
Comando:    cd "/var/www"
Error:  Directory /var/www: no such file or directory
Error:  Error al recuperar el listado del directorio (error on retrieving directory listing)
```

I need this user to be able to access /var/www as this is his only function.
The server has other users and I'm worried about breaking something if I mess arround with the permission of folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Match group sftp
ChrootDirectory /home
```

Your configuration is restricting sftp users to the `/home` directory and its subdirectory. In fact, the `/home` directory will appear as the root directory to these users. `/var/www` is outside of `/home`, so it's not accessible.

You could remove the "ChrootDirectory" directive from `sshd_config`. Users would have access to the entire filesystem, including `/var/www` (subject to file permissions).

Alternately, you could use a [bind mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount) to make `/var/www` accessible inside the `/home` directory. Bind mounts are commonly used in SFTP chroot environments.